# ¿Como puedo separar un string por caracteres? PHP Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, array

Buenas tardes Titanes de la programación, tengo un problema, yo estoy tomando de la base de datos un string el cual me da el siguiente valor `1101000100000000`, les explico para qué sirve este valor, cada carácter es un estado `0 = Cerrado` y `1 = Abierto` , y a la vez estos estados son puertas, osea tengo un total de 16 puertas que se abren y cierran, necesito separar cada carácter para asignarlo a una tabla que tengo, intente hacer el explode e implode en php pero al no tener un carácter con que separarlo no pude, hay otra forma para separarlo por php o hacerlo con jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes intentar dividirlo con split, esto te devolvera un array de chars con cada numero en una posicion.

```
$str = "Hello Friend";

$arr1 = str_split($str);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, voy a intentarlo.

Comment: @IsraelCorreaQuevedo De nada. Si te funciono, marca la respuesta como correcta.

Comment: me funciono perfectamente, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

creo que esto te podrá servir:

```
for ($x = 0;$x < strlen($palabra); $x++)
{
      // Aquí se almacena cada carácter.
      $palabra[$x];
}
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Un saludo.

Comment: gracias por responder, voy a intentarlo